# How to fill missing values for missing dates with value from date before in sql bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a product table with daily price, the catch here is that for the table only updates if there's a price change, and for the dates in between will not be written into the table because the price is the same as the day before.

How do I fill missing values of price  with the last entry of date before?

| date | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | 6 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 7 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 11 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 | 12 |

into

| date | id | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 | 5 |
| 2022-01-03 | 1 | 6 |
| 2022-01-04 | 1 | 6 |
| 2022-01-05 | 1 | 7 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 10 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2 | 11 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2 | 11 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 | 11 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2 | 11 |
| 2022-01-06 | 2 | 12 |

I am currently thinking of creating a table for dates and joining and using lag function. Anyone can help?

```
select
date,id,
case
when price is null then nullPrice 
else price
end as price
from(
select *,
Lag(price, 1) OVER(.
       ORDER BY date,id ASC) AS nullPrice
from price_table
join date_table using(date)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below:

```sql
WITH days_by_id AS (
  SELECT id, GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(MIN(date), MAX(date)) days
    FROM sample
   GROUP BY id
)
SELECT date, id, 
       IFNULL(price, LAST_VALUE(price IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date)) AS price
  FROM days_by_id, UNNEST(days) date LEFT JOIN sample USING (id, date);
```

output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use generate_date_array function for this

```
with date_arr
as(
select *
from unnest(generate_date_array('2022-01-01', '2022-05-01')) as dt)
select da.dt, t1.*
from date_arr da
left outer join table1 t1
on da.dt = t1.dt
```

You can replace hardcoded dates with max and min date from table.